Implement a small program to authenticate using 802.1X to a RADIUS client
I need to write a small program that allows you to enter a username and password and that performs authentication against a FREERADIUS client using wired 802.1X.So in this case my application will act as the supplicant. The program can be for Windows or Linux.
I have been looking for information about a library that implements the 802.1X protocol but I haven't found one. Is there a library that I can use? What options do I have?
